# Loading mongoose models with istanbul

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, istanbul

I want to implement code coverage for our project, so we use grunt-istanbul.
I'm sticking to this Tutorial: https://github.com/taichi/grunt-istanbul

My problem is, that I get this error when running the tests against the instrumentalized source code, but it works fine when running the test against the normal code.

```
>> Mocha exploded!
>> MongooseError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Comm".
>> Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
>>     at Mongoose.model (/Users/user/repos/review.ninja/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:322:13)
>>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/repos/review.ninja/test/coverage/instrument/src/server/api/comm.js:9:147)
>>     at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
>>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
>>     at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
>>     at require (module.js:373:17)
>>     at /Users/user/repos/review.ninja/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:172:27
>>     at Array.forEach (native)
>>     at Mocha.loadFiles (/Users/user/repos/review.ninja/node_modules/grunt-mocha-test/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:169:14)
```

We also export `mongoose.model('Comm', CommSchema);` in the comm module and import it in the test code. As said before, it works if running the Mocha tests normally.